# Is meta nofollow different from rel="nofollow"?

Tags: nofollow

If I put on my website `<meta name="robots" content="nofollow" />`, does that prevent from passing juice to **all** the links on my website (internal and external)?

Is the `nofollow` in meta any different from `rel="nofollow"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are for different things. The meta tag is for crawling - whether or not search engine robots should follow links on your page in order to find other pages to crawl. The `rel="nofollow"` attribute is specifically for links that shouldn't pass PageRank.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Meta Nofollow** = don't follow **all** links on this page
2. **Rel Nofollow** = don't follow **this** link.

Pretty simple distinction between the two.

Don't spider my website is the general message if you meta nofollow all your pages.

So, planning on having a sitemap.xml so Google can find more than the index page if you Meta Nofollow all the pages? How will Google determine the internal relevance of pages if it can't follow the link structure?

Most **link juice** questions are often over-thinking the issue and lead to SEO damage.

Create a useful website with useful content and a web of links to tie it together. Google fully understands this sort of website. Let the search engine have full access so your website gets completely indexed.

1. Use Meta Nofollow on things like login, cart and search pages to restrict spidering if someone links to them from another website.
2. Use link rel=nofollow the comments section on blogs to prevent spamming, on links to login pages, add to cart buttons, cart pages and other places where search engines don't belong to prevent following those specific links.